# Inrecept requests to specific beans

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm developing webapp using spring 3 mvc and using annotation-based controllers. I want to define an interceptor, that will intercept requests to specific beans not for all. How I can do that?

Now i use following config, but it intercept requests to all beans

```
 <bean id="annotationMapper" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="sessionInterceptor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean> 

<bean id="sessionInterceptor" class="app.interceptors.SessionCheckInterceptor"/>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring 3 you can bind interceptors to specific URLs using [`mvc` namespace](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/12/21/mvc-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/):

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <bean class="app.interceptors.SessionCheckInterceptor" />
        <mvc:mapping path = "/somePath/**" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

For more complex cases you may also use AOP to intercept controller method calls.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best choice for intercepting calls to your bean is using [Spring AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html).

```
@Aspect
public class AroundExample {

  @Around("com.xyz.myapp.SystemArchitecture.businessService()")
  public Object doBasicProfiling(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    // start stopwatch
    Object retVal = pjp.proceed();
    // stop stopwatch
    return retVal;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution using springplugins project (http://code.google.com/p/springplugins/)
It define two own mappers:

- SelectedAnnotationHandlerMapping handle only defined url's
- IgnoreSelectedAnnotationHandlerMapping handle all urs's except defined

If you know a better way to solve this problem, you a welcome